# SQL return all fields from max of count

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have tried but just cannot get the results so I'm asking for help here. I have a table of logins for users on computers. I want to count the number of times a user has logged into a computer and then get the max so that max user is considered the primary user of the computer.

[image: Example]

Comment: What tables with which exact columns do you have? Which rdbms are you using? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: see [tag:greatest-n-per-group] for many answers to this sort of question. Also please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557  Why is it easier to take a screenshot of your editor, save it locally, upload it to SO and link it in the question then to simply copy & paste the content of your editor. And tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Using SQL 2012 on the back-end and actually just using MS Access as the query engine.  Tried the following but it only returns 1 row instead of the results I'm trying to get as shown above (uh represents the table UserHist.  `SELECT uh.computer_id, uh.user_name, Count(uh.user_name)
FROM uh
GROUP BY uh.computer_id, uh.user_name
HAVING Count(uh.user_name)=(SELECT Max(a.cnt)
FROM (SELECT uh.computer_id, Count(uh.user_name) AS cnt
FROM uh
GROUP BY uh.computer_id, uh.user_name) AS a)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I tried to paste my question from text and have it look like it does in the pic so that the columns of data and requested results would be easier to read; but they kept wrapping instead of showing in columns.  When I finally did get a list of columns, it cut off the bottom half as if there was a character limit.  So I resorted to a screenshot to hopefully show how I'm trying to get several counts and their maxes.  And after reading the Because in post 285551, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what dbms you are using, you can use a window function ROW_NUMBER() to rank the counts per comp. Then pull the highest ranking.

```
SELECT 
  Comp,
  [User],
  Cnt
FROM
    (SELECT 
      Comp,
      [User],
      COUNT(1) AS Cnt,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Comp ORDER BY Count(1) DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM UserHist
    GROUP BY Comp, [User]) BaseTable
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `RANK` the counts and then select the largest.  This uses a CTE to get the data with the count and the rank.

```
WITH CTECOMP AS
(
SELECT COMP, [user], COUNT([USER]) [USERCOUNT], 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COMP ORDER BY COUNT([USER]) DESC ) [MYRANK]
FROM @TableData 
GROUP BY comp, [user]
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTECOMP 
WHERE MYRANK = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Comp, [User], count([User]) as MaxCnt
from TableHere
group by Comp, [User]
```